# setmask is not a function

Tags: javascript

Estou com um grande problema a muito tempo utilizo um *script* que sempre funcionou, porem hoje esta dando **"setmask is not a function"**. Irei mandar a chamada para ser analisada, também o *script* porem aviso que pode ser um pouco longo...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#txtCpf').setmask('cpf');
    });
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/fabiomcosta/jquery-meiomask/master/di‌​st/meiomask.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#txtCpf').setmask('cpf');
     });
</script>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="cpf" id="txtCpf" placeholder="CPF:049.253.241-24"/>
    <button value="enviar">
</form>
```

[image: Imagem do codigojuntamente ao erro..]

[image: chamada do script]

Comment: Tente mudar a URL do script para `https://cdn.rawgit.com/fabiomcosta/jquery-meiomask/master/dist/meiomask.js`. Provavelmente, vai funcionar, porém, como o [projeto](https://github.com/fabiomcosta/jquery-meiomask) não tem mais manutenção, sugiro você copiar o(s) arquivo(s) para um repositório seu

Comment: Estranho amigo é que sempre funcionou.. agora começou da esse erro..mas vou tentar mudando ...  pode ser um problema por ter mudado a biblioteca jquery...

Comment: Mas ao mudar a URL funcionou?

Comment: Não amigo não funcionou... tentei de tudo mudando posição e até alterando a biblioteca é estranho pois esse script funciona em outros sistemas...

Comment: Eu testei aqui o trecho de código que você postou e funcionou sem problemas (com a URL do comentário acima). No Firefox acontece o mesmo erro?

Comment: Tipo é estranho amigo pois acontece somente com esse sistema, meus outros sistemas funciona tranquilamente em todos os navegadores... 
e com o firefox tambem não funciona... @.@ amigo algum segredo quando voce testou a trecho do codigo voce fez algo tem como postar o que voce fez ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45785/discussion-between-elizandro-schmidt-and-gomiero).